# How to extract href using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, href

```
<a class="j-search-result-value jiveTT-hover-user" data-userid="12345" href="/people/ARNLWS"><span class="j-search-result-title">Aaron Lewis</span></a>

<a class="j-search-result-value jiveTT-hover-user" data-userid="99886" href="/people/DONLDTUMP"><span class="j-search-result-title">Donald Trump</span></a>
```

How to extract the href from above? I tried to use `find_element_by_class_name` but returns `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".j-search-result-value jiveTT-hover-user"}`

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'xxxx\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("xxx")

eList = driver.find_element_by_class_name('j-search-result-value jiveTT-hover-user')

hrefList = []
for e in eList:
   hrefList.append(e.get_attribute('href'))

for href in hrefList:
   print(href)
```

The reason why I didn't use `xpath` because it may vary based on the URLs.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: does `driver.find_element_by_class_name('j-search-result-value')` work?

Comment: It works partially but also returns other hrefs...

Comment: then  it's possible to filter out those other hrefs, for example hrefs which don't have "/people/... in is value..  there are many options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.find_element_by_class_name` just for single class name.

To collect elements list you have to use `.find_elements` not `.find_element`.

I suggest you use `.find_elements_by_css_selector` like this:

```
eList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.j-search-result-value.jiveTT-hover-user')
```

Comment: Thank you. ".find_elements_by_css_selector" works really well!

Answer (score 0):

Idea: 
Suggest to find those elements which contain `data-userid` attribute and then extract their `href` attribute:

Untested pseudocode:

```
eList = driver.find_elements_by_x_path('//a[@data-userid]')

hrefList = []
for e in eList:
   hrefList.append(e.get_attribute('href'))

for href in hrefList:
   print(href)
```